# QGIS - Rule-based Symbology - Added Ranges do not carry over Legend entries

Tags: qgis, symbology, legend, rule-based

When I add ranges to a rule, under Rule-based Symbology, the auto-populated (or modified) legend values do not carry over.  To fix this, I would have to manually change each line in the legend properties of the print layout.  Anyone know of a solution to get the legend values to carry over as it appears they were intended to do?